# Implement tokens in a SwiftUI TextField

Tags: ios, swiftui, tokenize

How can I make `TextField` in SwiftUI have tokens like an `UISearchBar`?

I've tried to insert an `UISearchBar` so I could use them, but I lost the behavior from the interaction between the `TextField` and the `List`.

Comment: Not now. Submit feedback to Apple and maybe in some of next versions...

Comment: Did you come up with any solution? I would like to use tokens in my text field.

Comment: Not directly. To use tokens, for now, we need to use an UITextField.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In iOS 16, Apple have added SwiftUI support for this to `searchable` view modifiers, e.g. `searchable(text:tokens:placement:prompt:token:)` ([API docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/form/searchable(text:tokens:placement:prompt:token:)-77cfu))

Example from [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/adding-search-to-your-app)

```swift
enum FruitToken: Identifiable, Hashable, CaseIterable {
    case apple
    case pear
    case banana
    var id: Self { self }
}

@State private var tokens: [FruitToken] = []

ProductList()
    .searchable(text: $text, tokens: $tokens) { token in
        switch token {
        case .apple: Text("Apple")
        case .pear: Text("Pear")
        case .banana: Text("Banana")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is it possible to make it work with previous versions of iOS ?

Comment: Nope, just available from iOS 16 unfortunately

Comment: @CMash Are tokens and `searchSuggestions` 2 ways of addressing the same problem? Or are they totally different things? Is it possible to use search tokens and search suggestions at the same time or not?

Answer (score 5):

For versions previous to iOS 16 the best way seems to make an `UIViewRepresentable` strut for a `UISearchBar` with tokens.

It has one binding for the search text stored in an array, `searchText`. In it each element will have the text of each token.

```
/// Brings UISearchBar to SwiftUI. This enables using tokens for searching for iOS and macOS.
struct TokenSearchBar {
    @Binding var searchText: [String]
}

extension TokenSearchBar: UIViewRepresentable {

    internal func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UISearchBar {
        //Configures the Search Bar
        let searchBar = UISearchBar()

        searchBar.delegate = context.coordinator

        return searchBar
    }

    func updateUIView(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, context: Context) {

        if context.coordinator.searchText != searchText {
            context.coordinator.searchText = searchText
        }
    }


    /// Coordinator and delegate for the searchbar
    internal class Coordinator: NSObject, UISearchBarDelegate {
        var parent: TokenSearchBar

        var searchBar: UISearchBar?

        var searchText: [String] = [] {
            didSet {
                guard let searchBar = searchBar else {
                    return
                }

                //get the current search array
                var tokenSearchText = searchText

                let lastSearchTextItem: String

                if tokenSearchText.isEmpty {
                    lastSearchTextItem = ""
                } else {
                    lastSearchTextItem = tokenSearchText.removeLast()
                }

                //compare them with the search array
                tokenSearchText.enumerated().forEach {
                    offset, searchString in

                    //Get the current tokens.
                    let currentTokens = searchBar.searchTextField.tokens

                    //Check if the number of tokens on display can be displayed with this offset. If not it will create a new token at the end.
                    if currentTokens.count > offset {

                        //Check if the token at this offset has the same object as the searchstring. If not will insert a new token on this offset.
                        //I will assume that all represented objects are strings
                        if let representedObject = currentTokens[offset].representedObject as? String, representedObject != searchString {
                            let newToken = UISearchToken(icon: nil, text: searchString)
                            newToken.representedObject = searchString

                            searchBar.searchTextField.tokens.insert(newToken, at: offset)
                        }

                    } else {
                        let newToken = UISearchToken(icon: nil, text: searchString)
                        newToken.representedObject = searchString

                        self.searchBar?.searchTextField.tokens.append(newToken)
                    }
                }

                //Trim the number of tokens to be equal to the tokenSearchText
                let tokensToRemove = searchBar.searchTextField.tokens.count - tokenSearchText.count
                if tokensToRemove > 0 {
                    searchBar.searchTextField.tokens.removeLast(tokensToRemove)
                }

                //make the search field text equal to lastSearchTextItem
                if searchBar.text != lastSearchTextItem {
                    searchBar.text = lastSearchTextItem
                }

                if parent.searchText != self.searchText {
                    parent.searchText = self.searchText

                }
            }
        }


        init(_ searchBar: TokenSearchBar) {
            self.parent = searchBar
        }

        //MARK: UISearchBarDelegate implementation
        func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
            self.searchBar = searchBar

            searchText = []
        }

        func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
            self.searchBar = searchBar

            //add a new level to the search
            if searchText.last?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines) != "" {
                searchText.append("")
            }
        }

        func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
            self.searchBar = searchBar

            if self.searchText.last != nil,  self.searchText[self.searchText.count - 1] != searchText {
                self.searchText[self.searchText.count - 1] = searchText
            } else {

                var tokenText = searchBar.searchTextField.tokens.compactMap{$0.representedObject as? String}

                tokenText.append(searchText)

                self.searchText = tokenText

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same issue, as [`NSTokenField`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstokenfield) is only available on macOS, not on iOS. `searchable` only supports iOS 16+, and it's not very flexible with UI customization. Also, it doesn't support multiline. Therefore, I created this custom [`TokenTextField`](https://github.com/JayantBadlani/TokenTextField_SwiftUI) class/library.

You can use the code below for Token TextField functionality in iOS SwiftUI, and find the complete source code here.

Feature Support

- Support iOS 15+
- Multiline Token TextField
- Customisable UI

[Result ScreenShot active text field state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLEMx.jpg)

[Result ScreenShot selected token state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brmZl.jpg)

##### EXAMPLE: How to Use

```swift
struct TokenFieldExampleView: View {
    
    @FocusState private var tagFieldFocusState: Bool
    @State private var tags: [TokenModel] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        
            TokenTextField(tags: $tags)
                .focused($tagFieldFocusState)
    }
}
```

##### SOURCE CODE

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct TokenTextField: View {
    
    @Binding var tags: [TokenModel]
    @State var horizontalSpacingBetweenItem: CGFloat = 10
    @State var verticalSpacingBetweenItem: CGFloat = 15
    
    var body: some View {
        
        TokenLayout(alignment: .leading, horizontalSpacingBetweenItem: horizontalSpacingBetweenItem, verticalSpacingBetweenItem: verticalSpacingBetweenItem) {
            ForEach(tags.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                TagView(tag: $tags[index], allTags: $tags)
                    .onChange(of: tags[index].value) { newValue in
                        handleTagChange(index: index, newValue: newValue)
                    }
                    .onTapGesture {
                        handleTagTap(index: index)
                    }
                    .id(tags[index].convertedToToken)
            }
        }
        .padding(.all, 15)
        .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.08))
        .cornerRadius(5)
        .onTapGesture {
            updateSelectedTag()
        }
        .onAppear {
            handleInitialTag()
        }
        .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification)) { _ in
            handleKeyboardWillHide()
        }
    }
    
    private func updateSelectedTag() {
        // if !tags.isEmpty && tags.allSatisfy({ !$0.isSelected }) {
        if !tags.isEmpty {
            tags.indices.forEach { index in
                if tags[index].isSelected {
                    tags[index].isSelected = false
                }
            }
            if !tags[tags.indices.last!].convertedToToken  {
                tags[tags.indices.last!].isSelected = true
            }
            else {
                appendEmptyTag(isSelected: true)
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func handleTagChange(index: Int, newValue: String) {
        guard !newValue.isEmpty else {
            return
        }
        
        if let lastCharacter = newValue.last, ",; ".contains(lastCharacter) {
            tags[index].value.removeLast()
            if !tags[index].value.isEmpty {
                appendEmptyTag(isSelected: true)
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func handleInitialTag() {
        if tags.isEmpty {
            appendEmptyTag(isSelected: false)
        }
        else if let lastTag = tags.last, lastTag.convertedToToken {
            appendEmptyTag(isSelected: false)
        }
    }
    
    private func handleKeyboardWillHide() {
        if let lastTag = tags.last, !lastTag.value.isEmpty {
            appendEmptyTag(isSelected: false)
        }
    }
    
    private func appendEmptyTag(isSelected: Bool) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            tags.indices.forEach { index in
                if !tags[index].convertedToToken && !(tags[index].value.isEmpty) {
                    tags[index].convertedToToken = true
                }
                if tags[index].isSelected {
                    tags[index].isSelected = false
                }
            }
            tags.append(TokenModel(value: "", isSelected: isSelected, convertedToToken: false))
        }
    }
    
    private func handleTagTap(index: Int) {
        tags.indices.forEach { tags[$0].isSelected = false }
        tags[index].isSelected = true
    }
}

struct TagView: View {
    
    @Binding var tag: TokenModel
    @Binding var allTags: [TokenModel]
    @FocusState private var isFocused: Bool
    @State private var isEditable: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        BackSpaceListnerTextField(
            tag: $tag,
            onBackPressed: {
                handleBackspacePressed()
            },
            isEditable: $isEditable
        )
        .focused($isFocused)
        .padding(.vertical, 3)
        .padding(.horizontal, 5)
        .background {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                .foregroundColor(isEditable ? Color.clear : (isFocused ? Color.accentColor : Color.gray.opacity(0.2)))
        }
        .frame(height: 21)
        .onTapGesture {
            handleTagTap()
        }
        .onChange(of: isFocused) { newValue in
            handleFocusChange()
        }
        .onChange(of: allTags) { newValue in
            handleTagFocusChange(newValue: newValue)
        }
        .onChange(of: tag.isSelected) { newValue in
            isEditable = !tag.convertedToToken
        }
        .onAppear() {
            isFocused = tag.isSelected
            isEditable = !tag.convertedToToken
        }
    }
    
    private func handleTagTap() {
        allTags.indices.forEach { allTags[$0].isSelected = false }
        tag.isSelected = true
        isFocused = tag.isSelected
    }
    
    
    private func handleBackspacePressed() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if let selectedTagIndex = allTags.firstIndex(where: { $0.isSelected }),
               allTags.count > 0 {
                if tag.value.isEmpty || (tag.isSelected && tag.convertedToToken) {
                    allTags.remove(at: selectedTagIndex)
                    
                    if !allTags.isEmpty {
                        allTags[allTags.indices.last!].isSelected = true
                    }
                }
            }
            
            if allTags.isEmpty {
                appendEmptyTag(isSelected: true)
                isEditable = true
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func appendEmptyTag(isSelected: Bool) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            allTags.indices.forEach { index in
                if !allTags[index].convertedToToken && !(allTags[index].value.isEmpty) {
                    allTags[index].convertedToToken = true
                }
                if allTags[index].isSelected {
                    allTags[index].isSelected = false
                }
            }
            allTags.append(TokenModel(value: "", isSelected: isSelected, convertedToToken: false))
        }
    }
    
    private func handleFocusChange() {
        tag.isSelected = isFocused
        
        if allTags.allSatisfy({ !$0.isSelected }), let lastTag = allTags.last, lastTag.convertedToToken == true {
            appendEmptyTag(isSelected: false)
        }
        else if allTags.allSatisfy({ !$0.isSelected }), let lastTag = allTags.last, lastTag.convertedToToken == false, !lastTag.value.isEmpty {
            allTags[allTags.indices.last!].convertedToToken = true
        }
    }
    
    private func handleTagFocusChange(newValue: [TokenModel]) {
        if newValue.last?.id == tag.id && (newValue.last?.isSelected ?? false) && !isFocused {
            isFocused = true
        }
    }
}

struct BackSpaceListnerTextField: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    @Binding var tag: TokenModel
    var onBackPressed: () -> ()
    @Binding var isEditable: Bool
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(text: $tag.value, isEditable: $isEditable, onBackPressed: onBackPressed)
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> CustomTextField {
        let textField = CustomTextField()
        textField.delegate = context.coordinator
        textField.onBackPressed = onBackPressed
        textField.keyboardType = .emailAddress
        textField.placeholder = "     "
        textField.autocorrectionType = .no
        textField.autocapitalizationType = .words
        textField.backgroundColor = .clear
        textField.addTarget(context.coordinator, action: #selector(Coordinator.textChange(textField:)), for: .editingChanged)
        return textField
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: CustomTextField, context: Context) {
        
        if (uiView.text?.count ?? 0) > 0 {
            uiView.placeholder = ""
        }
        else {
            uiView.placeholder = "     " // to initially give width to textfield
        }
        
        if !isEditable {
            uiView.text = tag.value
            uiView.tintColor = tag.isSelected ? .clear : .tintColor
            uiView.textColor = tag.isSelected ? .white : .black
        } else {
            uiView.text = tag.value
            uiView.tintColor = .tintColor
            uiView.textColor = .black
        }
    }
    
    func sizeThatFits(_ proposal: ProposedViewSize, uiView: CustomTextField, context: Context) -> CGSize? {
        return uiView.intrinsicContentSize
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {
        
        @Binding var text: String
        @Binding var isEditable: Bool
        var onBackPressed: () -> ()
        
        init(text: Binding<String>, isEditable: Binding<Bool>, onBackPressed: @escaping () -> ()) {
            self._text = text
            self._isEditable = isEditable
            self.onBackPressed = onBackPressed
        }
        
        @objc func textChange(textField: UITextField) {
            DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                self?.text = textField.text ?? ""
            }
        }
        
        func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
            textField.resignFirstResponder()
        }
        
        func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
            if !isEditable {
                if string.isEmpty {
                    onBackPressed()
                    return false
                } else {
                    return false
                }
            }
            return true
        }
    }
    
    class CustomTextField: UITextField {
        
        open var onBackPressed: (() -> ())?
        var isEditable: Bool = true
        
        override func deleteBackward() {
            if isEditable {
                super.deleteBackward()
                onBackPressed?()
            } else {
                // Handle deletion of the entire tag
                onBackPressed?()
            }
        }
        
        override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
            return false
        }
    }
}

struct TokenLayout: Layout {
    
    var alignment: Alignment = .center
    var horizontalSpacingBetweenItem: CGFloat = 10
    var verticalSpacingBetweenItem: CGFloat = 0

    func sizeThatFits(proposal: ProposedViewSize, subviews: Subviews, cache: inout ()) -> CGSize {
        let maxWidth = proposal.width ?? 0
        var totalHeight: CGFloat = 0

        let rows = generateRows(maxWidth, proposal, subviews)

        for (index, _) in rows.enumerated() {
            totalHeight += rows[index].maxHeight(proposal)
            totalHeight += index == rows.count - 1 ? 0 : verticalSpacingBetweenItem
        }

        return CGSize(width: maxWidth, height: totalHeight)
    }

    func placeSubviews(in bounds: CGRect, proposal: ProposedViewSize, subviews: Subviews, cache: inout ()) {
        var origin = CGPoint(x: bounds.origin.x, y: bounds.origin.y)

        let maxWidth = bounds.width
        let rows = generateRows(maxWidth, proposal, subviews)

        for (index, row) in rows.enumerated() {
            let totalWidth = row.reduce(0) { partialResult, view in
                let width = view.sizeThatFits(proposal).width
                return partialResult + width
            }
            let totalSpacing = CGFloat(row.count - 1) * horizontalSpacingBetweenItem
            let remainingSpace = maxWidth - totalWidth - totalSpacing

            switch alignment {
            case .leading:
                origin.x = bounds.minX
            case .trailing:
                origin.x = bounds.maxX - (totalWidth + totalSpacing)
            case .center:
                origin.x = bounds.minX + remainingSpace / 2
            default:
                break
            }

            for view in row {
                let viewSize = view.sizeThatFits(proposal)
                view.place(at: origin, proposal: proposal)
                origin.x += (viewSize.width + horizontalSpacingBetweenItem)
            }

            origin.y += (row.maxHeight(proposal) + (index == rows.count - 1 ? 0 : verticalSpacingBetweenItem))
        }
    }

    func generateRows(_ maxWidth: CGFloat, _ proposal: ProposedViewSize, _ subviews: Subviews) -> [[LayoutSubviews.Element]] {
        var row: [LayoutSubviews.Element] = []
        var rows: [[LayoutSubviews.Element]] = []
        var origin = CGRect.zero.origin

        for view in subviews {
            let viewSize = view.sizeThatFits(proposal)
            let totalWidth = origin.x + viewSize.width + (row.isEmpty ? 0 : horizontalSpacingBetweenItem)

            if totalWidth > maxWidth {
                rows.append(row)
                row.removeAll()
                origin.x = 0
            }

            row.append(view)
            origin.x += (viewSize.width + horizontalSpacingBetweenItem)
        }

        if !row.isEmpty {
            rows.append(row)
        }

        return rows
    }
}

struct TokenModel: Identifiable, Hashable, Equatable {
    
    var id: UUID = UUID()
    var value: String
    var isSelected: Bool = false
    var convertedToToken = true

    static func == (lhs: TokenModel, rhs: TokenModel) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id && lhs.value == rhs.value && lhs.isSelected == rhs.isSelected && lhs.convertedToToken == rhs.convertedToToken
    }
}

extension Array where Element == LayoutSubviews.Element {

    func maxHeight(_ proposal: ProposedViewSize) -> CGFloat {
        return self.compactMap { view in
            return view.sizeThatFits(proposal).height
        }.max() ?? 0
    }
}
```